# $\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be expressed as $A\cup B$ where $A,B$ are algebraic varieties

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer. I want to prove one of these:

1.$\mathbb{R}^n$ cannot be expressed as $A\cup B$ where $A,B$ are algebraic varieties $V(I),V(J)$ and $A,B\neq\mathbb{R}^n$.

2.$\mathbb{R}^n$ is not Haussdorff under Zariski's topology.

3.If $V(J)=\mathbb{R}^n$ then $J=0$.

where $I,J$ are ideals of the ring of polynomials in $n$ indeterminates.

I started trying to prove 2, then arrived to 1, which seemed very intuitive under the real numbers. But I still don't see how to prove it (I think there may be different ways to prove it outside of the algebraic geometry). Then I got to 3, but I don't think it's true in general (I'd have to use characteristic 0 I think).

Any idea or hint?

Comment: In 1, you need to say "unless $A = \Bbb{R}^n$ or $B = \Bbb{R}^n$".

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove 3 (for $\Bbb{R}$ or any infinite field), observe that if $K$ is any integral domain and $f \in K[x]$ has infinitely many roots, then $f = 0$. Use this to show (by induction on $n$) that if $f \in K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ satisfies $f(\mathbf{x}) = 0$ for every $\mathbf{x} \in K^n$, then $f = 0$.

The analogue of 3 if you replace $\Bbb{R}$ by a finite field is not true. E.g., Every element of $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is a zero of $x^2-x$.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was forgetting that if $f\in J$, then $V(J)\subseteq V(f)$, thus $V(f)=\mathbb{R}^n$ and I can use your hint (I see the proof within my reach).

Answer (score 1):

For I, just note that algebraic sets have empty interior for the usual topology. In particular $A\cup B$ is of empty interior.

Proof. Such a set is defined by a family of equations $f_i=0, i \in I$, where $f_i$ are not identically $0$.If it is not of empty interior, $f_i=0$ is not of empty interior. Using the Taylor formula around this interior point we see that $f_i=0$

For II, Apply I.

Comment: Yes, I'd looked into that, but hadn't thought about using Taylor formula. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a third perspective on the first question, you can prove the the zero set of any polynomial (so long as it is not all of $R^n$) has measure zero.

(As a hint, use Fubini's theorem to reduce to the one dimensional case.)

Comment: I hadn't thought about this (I haven´t seen anything about measure theory which different of probability so I don't know much yet), but it is very interesting to see different ways to prove it.

Comment: You don't need much measure theory to prove this, just the observation that the measure of a set $X$ in $R^n$ be obtained by the following recipe: pick some axis, and define a new function $\mu(a)$ given by the $R^{n-1}$ measure of the intersection of $X$ with the plane $z = a$. Then the measure of $X$ is the integral of $\mu$ along the $z$axis. But by the inductive hypothesis (using that in the base case, the zero set of a polynomial is a finite set of points, hence measure zero), each $\mu(a) = 0$, so the total measure is zero. ($X \cap (z = a)$ is still algebraic.)

Comment: The OP's three statements remain true if you replace $\Bbb{R}$ by any infinite field $K$. Is there a suitable measure theory proof of the more general statement?

Comment: @RobArthan I think that's an interesting question. The Haar measure doesn't appear to work, at least if you naively give $K$ the discrete topology, since then finite sets have positive measure (inner regularity + nontriviality of the measure + compact sets are finite forces finite sets to have positive measure), and so the inductive step fails since the integral has no guarantee to be finite. For fields that have a natural topology or measure ($\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, p-adics), then I think the same argument works. I am not sure what to do with $\overline{F_p}$, for example.